# Executing the ls command and storing output in variables

Tags: linux, shell

command is:-

```
ls-ltr|grep "$(date  +'%b %e')"|cut -d' ' -f14
```

the out will give file names created today.
i need to know how can i store individual files in individual variables.
example if i have 2 files in output and i want to store the two files in 2 different variables. Please help me how to do it

Comment: [why not parse ls output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: You mean `var1=$(<file1)` and `var2=$(<file2)`??

Comment: You might ask this on https://unix.stackexchange.com but delete this one if you do.

Comment: Why put them in different variables instead of an array?

Comment: I guess that depends on whether this is really POSIX shell or bash, etc.

Comment: not sure how your command will work.... i am new to linux....        
xyz@localhost ~]$ ls -ltr|grep "$(date +'%b %e')"|cut -d' ' -f12
a.txt
b.txt                                                                                                                         if this is my command output... then how can store the file names a.txt in one variable and b.txt in other vairable....

Comment: Barmar how to store it in an array?

Comment: `arrayname=($(command))` will execute a command and store its output into the array.

Comment: ok great that worked!!thank you :)

Comment: That assumes your filenames do not contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

If you are sure your filenames do not contain whitespace characters, you can do

```
todayfiles=( $(stat -c "%y@%n" * | grep "^$(date "+%F")" | cut -d@ -f2-) )
```

If your filenames might contain spaces or tabs, but you are sure they do not contain newline characters, you can do

```
mapfile -t todayfiles < <(stat -c "%y@%n" * | grep "^$(date "+%F")" | cut -d@ -f2-)
```

If you want to be able to handle any arbitrary filename, you can do

```
today=$(date "+%F")
todayfiles=()
for f in *; do
    stat -c "%y" "$f" | grep -q "^$today" && todayfiles+=("$f")
done
```

Then iterate over today's files with:

```
for f in "${todayfiles[@]}"; do ...; done
```